# Unable to recreate a PostgreSQL DB from a provided .sql file

Tags: postgresql

I am completely new to the world of PostgreSQL, please be patient with me.

I've been provided with a .sql file (the whole file here: [db-e4w.zip](http://hlou.ch/temp/db-e4w.zip)) which seems to be exported via Navicat from PGSQL server.
Start of the file (just in case anyone would try it the file is to be found here).

```
/*
Navicat PGSQL Data Transfer

Source Server         : pluto
Source Server Version : 80311
Source Host           : localhost:5432
Source Database       : kun3
Source Schema         : public

Target Server Type    : PGSQL
Target Server Version : 90100
File Encoding         : 65001

Date: 2012-06-07 11:24:41
*/
```

My problem is that I am unable to recreate the original database from the query contained in the provided file. I've tried via SQL command in pgAdmin III, Navicat PGSQL, and phpPgAdmin all with no success. I usually end up with hundreds of mistakes, one of the first is:

```
SQL error:
ERROR:  relation "core_log_log_id_log_seq" does not exist
```

Which is a result of this query (first of the sql file)

```
CREATE TABLE "core_log_log" (
"id_log" int4 DEFAULT nextval('core_log_log_id_log_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"message_log" text,
"priority_log" int2,
"date_creation_log" timestamp(6) DEFAULT NULL::timestamp without time zone,
"server_log" char(255) DEFAULT NULL::bpchar,
"idusr_log" int4,
"exception_log" text,
"idvis_log" int4
)
WITH (OIDS=TRUE)

;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. **Even if someone would just come up with something like** *the file is corrupted or incomplete, get a new and proper one* **or** *you are riding a completely false horse - try to import it this other way* **would help a bunch.**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is nothing like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE core_log_log_id_log_seq ...
```

In there before it is referencing the sequence, I would think it to be incomplete.

Comment: Thanks again. Now before jumping on learning sequences, is there a way to get a complete database dump (sql file) which would allow me to recreate the original database without any edits. I aware of that this is not directly related to the solution of procesing the original SQL and therefore a little misleading question, but before I'd start with fixing this provided SQL file, I'd preferably ask the provider for another - more complete version of it. Would you mind to share any hint of what is the safest way of exporting/importing PGSQL db I should ask them for?

Comment: I would assume Navicat would allow a full export.  I imagine it needs to be told to export sequences, since you may not always want to "really really" re-create the entire database, instead just re-build tables and data.  I would think it'd just be an option somewhere in the export process to export sequences as well.

Sorry, not a Navicat user!  Best of luck!

Comment: I will try to ask for that. Hope I will end up with a fully working file. If not, you'll have me back here soon. :)
Thank you again.

Comment: @ddhh Ask them to use pg_dump to export the database if NaviCat doesn't do the job.

Comment: I will try that. However I'm afraid it's not Navicat who does not do the job, it's them... We'll see. Thanks!